# Bootstrap3 Modal - Select2 Ajax Issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

So here goes another annoying issue, Select2, Bootstrap3 Modal.

I'm using select2 successfully across my site, the client wants a popup modal with a quick company select in. So after using the same select2 method I've got working across the application the modal launches, and i'm binding the select2 on bootstraps modal shown event. This is successfully attaching the select2, the only issue is that its not firing the ajax call!

I'm remote loading the html view into my modal container and have tried the css hacks and the enForce bootstrap modal modifications with no success.

Any help appreciated as I've run out of internet help and patience with this one.

Comment: Any code samples of what you tried would be brilliant.

Comment: `code`dropdownContainer  : $("#select").closest(".modal")`code`

Comment: $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};

Comment: This is a common problem when using bootstrap and select2, there just isn't a solution which solves my problem, but i have the same issue

Comment: After some faffing about and testing it looks like the issue is related to loading content remotely. It doesn't seem to fire ajax calls if html is loaded remotely, works fine if the content is on the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have this working on a few of my projects, post some code so i can see what youre doing

Comment: I was trying to create a fiddle but got stuck due to remote loading of views, I shall try and put something together later today to demonstrate my issue

Comment: So this is odd, after creating a fiddle this seems to work!! i shall debug locally and see what the issue is... http://jsfiddle.net/plumpscreative/65ux28rt/11/

Answer (score 0):

The issue on this was due to using the latest select2, you cannot use an input now you have to use a select box. Works as expected now...thanks for all your help